# XLSX library is not functional

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to use a javascript to append a field in HTML table after searching for the value in the excel sheet,
but unfortunately it shows nothing, i have installed all the necessary library but still it shows nothing,
i have tried to add console.log('Hello); in the beginning of the script but it didn't appear,
after deleting the XLSX src the console appear but i can't access the excel sheet it require the XLSX src,

so please any solution for this error?

below is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search Results</title>

    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 1em;
            min-width: 400px;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #008CBA;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: left;
            border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        td {
            padding: 10px;
            border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="results">
        </tbody>
    </table>

    
    <script lang="javascript" src="cdn.sheetjs.com_xlsx-0.20.0_package_dist_xlsx.full.min.js">
      
        const XLSX = require('xlsx');

        const workbook = XLSX.readFile('MM.xlsx');
        const worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'];

        const searchTerm = 'VIP1';
        const resultsTable = document.getElementById('results');
        for (const cellAddress in worksheet) {
            const cell = worksheet[cellAddress];
            
            if (cell.v === searchTerm) {
                const row = document.createElement('tr');
                const cell1 = document.createElement('td');
                cell1.innerText = cell.v;
                row.appendChild(cell1);
                const cell2 = document.createElement('td');
                cell2.innerText = 'Data 2';
                row.appendChild(cell2);
                const cell3 = document.createElement('td');
                cell3.innerText = 'Data 3';
                row.appendChild(cell3);
                resultsTable.appendChild(row);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to change the excel file,
tried to download the (src) data and import it,
tried to rearrange the code and change a couple of lines, but nothing work...

Please advise

Comment: for one thing, you can't have code inside a script that has a `src` attribute - so that code you've shown won't ever run

Comment: Note: once you fix the above, you don't use `const XLSX = require('xlsx');` as a) `require` isn't valid without the requierjs library, and b) `XLSX` is declared by the library you are loading